# Busca com javascript

Tags: javascript, algoritmo-de-busca

estou com um sistema de busca que apresenta o problema:
 - Retorna todos os valores de uma lista, quando apagado elemento do campo de pesquisa, o esperado é que se retorne somente os elementos iniciais, não todos.
Esta é a função de busca que estou usando:

```
$scope.$watch('q', function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if (oldValue != null) {
        $http.get('/api/services.json?q=' + newValue)
          .success(function (data) {
              $scope.services = data;
                      });
      };
      if (oldValue == null){
          $http.get('/api/services.json?q=' + oldValue)
            .success(function (data) {
              $scope.services = data;
               });
      }

    }, true);
```

Comment: O mais indicado neste caso, seria no server-side você limitar a quantidade de resultados quando o parâmetro for nulo ou vazio.

Comment: Posso fazer isso nos controller?

Comment: Consegue editar a pergunta e adicionar o código do seu controller?

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 1):

O ideal seria que você filtrasse a sua busca no servidor para não consumir recurso. Porém se você quiser limitar o número de registros no `AngularJS` você pode usar o filtro `limitTo`:

**[limitTo](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo)**

> Cria um novo `array` ou `string` contendo apenas o número especificado de elementos. Os elementos são tirados do início ou final do `array` base, `string` ou `number`, como específicado pelo valor e sinal (positivo ou negativo) do limite.

O uso se dá por:

**HTML**

```
{{ limitTo_expression | limitTo : limit : begin}}
```

**Javascript**

```
$filter('limitTo')(input, limit, begin)
```

**No seu exemplo ficaria**

```
$scope.services = $filter('limitTo')(data, 5, 0);
```

**Exemplo funcional:**

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('appExemploLimitado', []);

  angular
    .module('appExemploLimitado')
    .controller('LimiteController', LimiteController);

  LimiteController.$inject = ['$filter'];

  function LimiteController($filter) {
    var limite = this;
    
    iniciar();
    
    function iniciar() {
      limite.registros = [];
      limite.registros.push('Registro 1');
      limite.registros.push('Registro 2');
      limite.registros.push('Registro 3');
      limite.registros.push('Registro 4');
      limite.registros.push('Registro 5');
      limite.registros.push('Registro 6');
      limite.registros.push('Registro 7');
      limite.registros.push('Registro 8');
      limite.registros.push('Registro 9');
      limite.registros.push('Registro 10');

      limite.maximo = 5;
    }
  }
})()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div ng-app="appExemploLimitado">
  <div ng-controller="LimiteController as limite">
    Máximo de registros: <input type="number" name="input" ng-model="limite.maximo" min="1" max="10" required>
    <div ng-repeat="registro in limite.registros | limitTo:limite.maximo:0">
        <h3>{{registro}}</h3>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```